# Show a DialogFragment in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a class which is derived from `Android.App.DialogFragment`, now I need to show this dialog fragment. I am trying to show this dialog fragment from a class which is derived from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`. The following code is what I use to show the `DialogFragment`:

```
 Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            PlaylistSettingsDialogFragment psdf = new PlaylistSettingsDialogFragment();
            psdf.Show(ft, "PlaylistSettings");
```

I get a error from the last line. It says:

> Cannot convert the first parameter(ft) from
>   Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction to
>   Android.App.FragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

**Show** method for DialogFragment has 2 variants:

```
int     Show(FragmentTransaction transaction, String tag)
```

or

```
void    Show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)
```

so You can use it like this:

```
Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
PlaylistSettingsDialogFragment psdf = new PlaylistSettingsDialogFragment();
var transactionId = psdf.Show(ft, "PlaylistSettings");
```

or

```
PlaylistSettingsDialogFragment psdf = new PlaylistSettingsDialogFragment();
psdf.Show(FragmentManager, "PlaylistSettings");
```

Comment: I tryied both on them. In the first case I get the same error. If I use the second solution I get an error which says: cannot convert from Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager to Android.App.FragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use these lines of code to use Dialog Fragment in xamarin android i hope it helps!

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = _activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    //remove fragment from backstack if any exists
                    Fragment fragmentPrev = _activity.FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(_activity.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.dialogfragment_tag_name));
                    if (fragmentPrev != null)
                        fragmentTransaction.Remove(fragmentPrev);
                    fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null);
                    DialogFragmentFeedBackRating dialogFragment = DialogFragmentFeedBackRating.NewInstace(null,_activity);
                    dialogFragment.Show(fragmentTransaction, _activity.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.dialogfragment_tag_name));
```